# Associating boolean values with Ellipse2D objects

Tags: java, swing

With the code provided I want to make it more object oriented.  Specifically, I would like to associate a boolean (on or off) with each Ellipse that tells the graphics what color to draw it.  One color for true and a different color for false.

My question is:  What is the best way to define an Ellipse object that tells the graphics how to draw it and associate a boolean value to each object?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SelfContainedExample extends JPanel {
    private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGUI());
    }

    public SelfContainedExample()
    {
        //Circle of Radios
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(110, 70, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(90, 80, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 100, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(70, 120, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(90, 140, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(110, 150, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(130, 140, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(150, 120, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(150, 100, 15, 15));
        shapes.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(130, 80, 15, 15));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        shapes.forEach(g2d::fill);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
        JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Example",
                false,   //resizable
                false,   //closable
                false,   //maximizable
                true);  //iconifiable

        internalFrame.setSize(260, 260);
        internalFrame.add(new SelfContainedExample());
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);

        desktopPane.add(internalFrame);
        desktopPane.setVisible(true);
        desktopPane.setBounds(inset, inset,
                screenSize.width - inset * 7,
                screenSize.height - inset * 4);

        frame.add(desktopPane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(desktopPane.getSize());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( false );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setContentPane( desktopPane );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a wrapper or proxy class which contains a `boolean` property and a `Ellipse2D` property

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you elaborate?  Maybe provide some sample code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a wrapper class which maintained a reference to the `Ellipse` and it's state...

```
public class ColourFullShape {
    private Shape shape;
    private boolean state;

    public ColourFullShape(Shape shape, boolean state) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

}
```

Equally, you could just write a proxy `Shape` class:

```
public class ColourFullShape implements Shape {
    private Shape shape;
    private boolean state;

    public ColourFullShape(Shape shape, boolean state) {
        this.shape = shape;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return getShape().getBounds();
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle2D getBounds2D() {
        return getShape().getBounds2D();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
        return getShape().contains(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point2D p) {
        return getShape().contains(p);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean intersects(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        return getShape().intersects(x, y, w, h);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D r) {
        return getShape().intersects(r);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(double x, double y, double w, double h) {
        return getShape().contains(x, y, w, h);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Rectangle2D r) {
        return getShape().contains(r);
    }

    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at) {
        return getShape().getPathIterator(at);
    }

    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at, double flatness) {
        return getShape().getPathIterator(at, flatness);
    }

}
```